# Adding ortho images in Java project ArcGIS (SDK ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, java, orthophoto, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I would like to use my orthophoto in my project. I'm using ArcGIS SDK Java and the component:

```
ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.createStreetsVector());
```

My orthophoto size is 4 GB (.7z)

Comment: `.7z` is a 7Zip archiving format. What is inside the archive?

Comment: @Vince inside the archive : a lot of file with extension .JP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : use Raster class.

If you want to load some ortho images use this :

```
Raster raster = new Raster("path_ortho_file"); // jp2 format
// create a raster layer
RasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer(raster);
// add the raster as an operational layer
map.getOperationalLayers().add(rasterLayer);
```

If you want to load all files (jp2) from a directory : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301085/7568301